# how to clean dict values ( u'variables') in python?

Tags: python

i have this code :

```
t =  { u'last_name': [u'hbkjh'], u'no_of_nights': [u'1'], u'check_in': [u'2012-03-19'], u'no_of_adult': [u'', u'1'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'05e5bdb542c3be7515b87e8160c347a0'], u'memo': [u'kjhbn'], u'totalcost': [u'1800.0'], u'product': [u'4'], u'exp_month': [u'1'], u'quantity': [u'2'], u'price': [u'900.0'], u'first_name': [u'sdhjb'], u'no_of_kid': [u'', u'0'], u'exp_year': [u'2012'], u'check_out': [u'2012-03-20'], u'email': [u'ebmalifer@agile.com.ph'], u'contact': [u'3546576'], u'extra_test1': [u'jknj'], u'extra_test2': [u'jnjl'], u'security_code': [u'3245'], u'extra_charged': [u'200.0']}
{k: v for k,v in t.iteritems() if k.startswith('extra_')}
```

it gives me the output of :

```
{u'extra_charged': [u'200.0'], u'extra_test1': [u'jknj'], u'extra_test2': [u'jnjl']}
```

is it possible that i can clean the output or remove the `first u, [, ],`?

just like this...

```
{'extra_charged': '200.0', 'extra_test1': 'jknj', 'extra_test2': 'jnjl'}
```

Comment: u means unicode, it's totally correct, django loves unicode, if you want to output json, use json lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> {str(k): str(v[0]) for k,v in t.iteritems() if k.startswith('extra_')}
{'extra_charged': '200.0', 'extra_test1': 'jknj', 'extra_test2': 'jnjl'}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, I tried this piece of code, but it just gives me `{}` as result.
What I have before the "cast" is `{u'myProgRun': {u'debugging': {u'@level': 0} ...`.
Any tip?

Answer (score 2):

Grab the first item in the list  with `[0]`:

```
>>> {k: v[0] for k,v in t.iteritems() if k.startswith('extra_')}
{u'extra_charged': u'200.0', u'extra_test1': u'jknj', u'extra_test2': u'jnjl'}
```

The `u` just indicates that the string is a unicode string. You could convert this to ascii, but I'm not sure why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

'u' means its unicode - not in the string

'[]' means its a list

',' means its seperate items in a list.

Its just the way python shows it. if you want the string you have to access the lists.